# Get dynamically created checkbox values but from onprerender stage

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I am trying to dynamically generate checkbox controls in web part (SP 2010) but the number of checkboxes that has to be created depends on the value from previous web part. Abiding by the web part communication infrastructure, I can get that value only on "onprerender" stage. But if I try to create checkboxes with that value count, I cannot get the selected values of the checkbox on postback! I am aware that dynamically created controls should be placed either in page_load or oninit. But, here am supposed not to put there since am getting the particular value in prerender stage. Please help! Am struck with this!

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net needs you to recreate dynamically added controls on every `Init` after they are first added, till you require those controls on page.

You can use a `Session` variable to keep track of your count.

If a control is not present when the `ProcessPostData` method is invoked(Called just after LoadViewState), you cannot receive user input for them. Events like CheckedChanged also will fire only if your controls are present in the Controls collection before `ProcessPostData` is called.

Refer: [Page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply! But, the thing is that am not supposed to enable session variables.

Comment: You could use the ViewState, since `LoadViewState` is called just before this. As this is not an event, you would have to override the `LoadViewState` method.